# How to solve: Nuget Visual Studio 2019 message Project 'Default' not found

Tags: nuget-package, sql-server-data-tools, visual-studio-2019

I have an SSDT project and I open the Package Manager Console to use nuget to get a dacpac (in the repo already)  and I get these errors:

```
PM> get-Package -ListAvailable -AllVersions -IncludePrerelease 
get-Package : Project 'Default' is not found.
At line:1 char:1
+ get-Package -ListAvailable -AllVersions -IncludePrerelease
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Default:String) [Get-Package], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetProjectNotFound,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.GetPackageCommand
```

I do not have a project called "default" (the projects are named after the databases they contain) and I cannot see a way to mark a project as Default.  OTOH I can and do have a project marked as the startup project.

What is causing this error message and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a current limitation within Visual Studio SSDT projects.  I opened a ticket in the Visual Studio Feedback Forum with the name

```
VS 2019 Manage NuGet Packages should support Database project
```

[VS 2019 Manage NuGet Packages should support Database project](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/831672/vs-2019-manage-nuget-packages-should-support-datab.html)